# ¿Como evitar que se dupliquen datos en un combobox?

Tags: c#, mysql

Buen dia, tengo un error con mi proyecto, resulta que en mi combobox tengo registrados 4 productos, pero al momento de cambiar de seleccion y volver a la misma, estos productos se duplican, ¿como puedo corregir eso?
estoy trabajando en windows form enlazado a un base de datos MYSQL

```
string consulta = string.Format("Select precio from productos where nombre='Pacifica012'");
        string consulta2 = string.Format("Select precio from productos where nombre='GRG170DX'");
        string consulta3 = string.Format("Select precio from productos where nombre='Stratocaster S'");
        //MessageBox.Show(consulta);

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
        MySqlCommand comando2 = new MySqlCommand(consulta2, conexion2);
        MySqlCommand comando3 = new MySqlCommand(consulta3, conexion3);

        MySqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
        MySqlDataReader lector2 = comando2.ExecuteReader();
        MySqlDataReader lector3 = comando3.ExecuteReader();

        while (lector.Read())
        {

                textBox5.Text = lector.GetString(0);
        }
        while (lector2.Read())
        {

                textBox5.Text = lector2.GetString(0);
        }
        while (lector3.Read())
        {

                textBox5.Text = lector3.GetString(0);
        }
```

Comment: Agrega por favor el código para que podamos ayudarte, de esta forma es muy difícil.

Comment: Un docente de una universidad me ha aclarado la duda. Gracias por su interés :)

Comment: El código que has añadido no parece tener relación con el problema que describes en la pregunta (a simple vista no hay ningún combobox, ni ninguna acción al cambiar la selección).

Answer (score 0):

Debe ser que estás cargando los datos de los productos ante un evento show o similar; deberías buscar otro elemento o primero consultar si ya el combobox está lleno, o primero vaciarlo antes de llenarlo.